# Google Chrome extension to hide the LinkedIn feed

Tags: chrome, linkedin

I am looking for a Google Chrome extension to hide the LinkedIn feed. Any license or price is fine.

I unsuccessfully tried (they don't hide the LinkedIn feed):

- [News Feed Eradicator for LinkedIn](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/news-feed-eradicator-for/fcnlpkohldehaafajgejaplghjojeekg)
- [Loi LinkedIn News Feed + Sidebar Remover](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/loi-linkedin-news-feed-%20/ghjmoikjepilffofgnhmilpbeckpcpbn?hl=en)

Comment: What was unsuccessful about the two extensions you tried? Including that information may help others come up with a useful solution.

Comment: @freginold good point, I forgot to write it, question edited. Thanks!

Comment: Do you just mean the main (central) column on your LinkedIn home page?

Comment: @freginold yes~~~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a Chrome extension that hides the LinkedIn feed:

- [**LI Feed Hider**](https://tech-in-check.blogspot.com/2018/02/chrome-extension-to-hide-linkedin-feed.html)

(*Disclaimer*: I made it.)

It's a content script so it works automatically once you install it. It's nothing fancy -- just hides the feed column when you're on LinkedIn.

[image]

Comment: Is there a similar thing for firefox?

Answer (score 1):

Over the past few days I made a Chrome and Firefox extension that allows for customization of the feed, including but not limited to hiding it.

Check it out - **[on the official GitHub](https://github.com/njelich/linkoff)**